# Order By 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table and .

```
 id  |  item_id  | created_at 
-----+-----------+------------
  1  |   Apple   | 2017-03-21
  2  |   Grape   | 2017-03-23
  3  |   Grape   | 2017-03-24
  4  |   Apple   | 2017-03-25
```

I want to order by **created_at** and also at the same time order by **item_id** like this:

```
 id  |  item_id  | created_at 
-----+-----------+------------
  4  |   Apple   | 2017-03-25
  1  |   Apple   | 2017-03-21
  3  |   Grape   | 2017-03-24
  2  |   Grape   | 2017-03-23
```

So if i add a new row for **item_id: Grape** my new results should be like this:

```
 id  |  item_id  | created_at 
-----+-----------+------------
  5  |   Grape   | 2017-03-28  (NEW)
  3  |   Grape   | 2017-03-24
  2  |   Grape   | 2017-03-23
  4  |   Apple   | 2017-03-25
  1  |   Apple   | 2017-03-21
```

and then if i add new row for **item_id: Apple** it should be like this:

```
 id  |  item_id  | created_at 
-----+-----------+------------
  6  |   Apple   | 2017-03-28  (NEW)
  4  |   Apple   | 2017-03-25
  1  |   Apple   | 2017-03-21
  5  |   Grape   | 2017-03-27
  3  |   Grape   | 2017-03-24
  2  |   Grape   | 2017-03-23
```

...So it orders by the latest **created_at** and show the other rows with the same **item_id** below it

I have tried `ORDER BY created_at, item_id  DESC` but it does not works and give me this instead:

```
 id  |  item_id  | created_at 
-----+-----------+------------
  6  |   Apple   | 2017-03-28
  5  |   Grape   | 2017-03-27
  4  |   Apple   | 2017-03-25
  3  |   Grape   | 2017-03-24
  2  |   Grape   | 2017-03-23
  1  |   Apple   | 2017-03-21
```

Comment: 1. group by item_id 2. get row_number() 3. make a nested query and select other columns, with sorting by row_number(), created_at desc

Comment: @zerkms do you have a full example query?

Comment: Just do it step by step, ask a particular question when stuck (ps: my advice is actual for ANSI SQL and postgresql, since mysql does not support window functions)

Comment: Don't you know that you are asking a multiple kind of databases. And expect that you got a multiple type of queries too. Not all queries are working with 3 different types of databases.

Comment: You can use variable in mysql.  I posted an answer which uses that.

Comment: Nevermind, I see the other mysql answer which uses just max and is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [SQLFiddle: PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8557a8/2)

```
WITH grouped AS (
  select   item_id, max(created_at) as max_dt
  from     tbl 
  group by item_id
)
SELECT     tbl.*
FROM       grouped
LEFT JOIN  tbl      USING (item_id)
ORDER BY   grouped.max_dt desc, 
           grouped.item_id,      -- important if apple and grape both have same max dt
           tbl.created_at desc;
```

- subquery to get the most recent dates by item (the item grouping)
- left join those results on the actual table to get desired records

Answer (score 2):

You need to first identify your first rule which is get the max `created_at` per `item_id`, therefore the subquery with the `item_id` grouped and a `row_number()` added so it can know which fruit cames first. Then just join with your table.

```
SELECT tt.id, tt.item_id, tt.created_at
  FROM test_table tt
         INNER JOIN
      (SELECT item_id, 
              MAX(created_at),
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC) rn
         FROM test_table
        GROUP BY item_id
        ORDER BY 3) ord
     ON tt.item_id = ord.item_id
 ORDER BY ord.rn, tt.created_at DESC;
```

Comment: You don't have sorting in the nested query, hence the `ROW_NUMBER()` is not ordered.

Comment: Great, now this is the best looking answer, +1 :-)

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I was preparing the setup in my machine to test my solution and when I came back it was exactly what you suggested in comments. @zerkms

Comment: When i add a new row for Grape all the other Grape rows does not move to the top but instead all Apple rows are still at the top. I would like for the latest created_at Fruit to move to the top with all it's similar Fruit rows

Comment: I think I forgot to add the DESC on the order by in the subquery. Try it now please.

Comment: It's still the same result

Comment: I think I've fixed it now. Tested it and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

For mysql, try this:

```
select item.*
from item
left join (
    select item_id, max(created_at) maxdate
    from item
    group by item_id
) t on item.item_id = t.item_id
order by t.maxdate desc, item.created_at desc
```

### Demo1 in SQLFiddle




### Demo2 in SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Please try -

```
SELECT id,
       item_ID,
       created_at
FROM tblOrders
ORDER BY item_ID,
         item_ID = ( SELECT item_ID
                     FROM tblOrders
                     WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX( id ) FROM tblOrders ) ),
         created_at;
```

Comment: I will test this shortly in a similar database of mine, once I find one that is suitable and adapt the statement to suit.

Comment: Oh, boy was I way off.  I have changed my answer to something that I have tested and confirmed as working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mysql version

```
set @ordr = 0;
select t.*
from tbl t
join (
    select o.item_id, o.created_at, @ordr := @ordr + 1 as `order`
    from (
        select tbl.item_id, max(tbl.created_at) as created_at
        from tbl
        group by tbl.item_id
        order by created_at desc
    ) as o
) sub
on t.item_id = sub.item_id
order by sub.`order`, sub.created_at desc
```